# capture/trace requests to a certain url - iis

Tags: c#, iis, request, trace, capture

Is there a way to capture/trace/log all GET's or POST's to a certain url on IIS..?

I'd like capture calls to certain url for a few minutes for analysis. Be able to look into the headers, payloads, IP, etc..

I can write C# to do it, but was wondering if there's a diagnostics tool to do it already..?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS captures all requests by default.
You can find logs at C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1

You can parse the logs to filter out the URLs you are interested in.

Comment: Looks like my logs are here:  C:\Inetpub\vhosts\[DOMAIN]\statistics\logs